# SonarQube Issues View

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-ops

I want sonarQube administrators to have view of all the issues of every project and to whom they are assigned to in a single view like "user account page"

I am just able to see issues assigned to me

Could anybody tell can this be achieved. I am using SonarQube LTS 5.6.7 ??

Comment: It looks like you have to build your own SonarQube plugin using the SonarQube Web API.

Comment: Could these administrators use the issue search and filter on the assignee?